# i want to use curved image on the bottom like i posted

Tags: html, css

[image]

I want create this.

What I have so far is this, but it is not responsive as screen size changes. It stays on specific width, that is why i am thinking to replace this with image

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="betn-footer">
   </div>
</div>

.betn-footer{
    background-color:#f4f3f3;
    height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    border-bottom-left-radius:50%;
    border-bottom-right-radius:50%;
    margin-top:-20px;
    margin-left:65px;
    width:973.88px;
    box-shadow: 0 21px 30px -10px #080808;
}
```

Tell me if there is any other option to do this. Thank you!

Comment: You can change the width from a set `px` width to a `%`.

Comment: i tried this but with each screen size i have to change left margin

Comment: Are you using bootstrap or is `container-fluid` class your own?

Comment: I am using bootstrap

Comment: It might be easier just to use a background image.

Comment: if you want to use responsive you must not hardcode the margin-left of your image. use % percentage instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove your fixed widths and margins:

```css
.container-fluid { margin-bottom: 2em; }

.betn-footer {
  background-color: #f4f3f3;
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 21px 30px -10px #080808;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid" style="width:200px;">
   <div class="betn-footer"></div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid" style="width:500px;">
   <div class="betn-footer"></div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid" style="width:1000px;">
   <div class="betn-footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thakyou I gave same width and put     margin:auto for both divs thankyou for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You should not use margin-left and instead center the footer / your content with **margin: 0 auto**. Then you can set your footer width to a flexible width via using **%**

Answer (score 0):

```
IMG.displayed {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto }
...
<IMG class="displayed" src="..." alt="...">
```

it will always display a picture in the center of the page.